# Core Data No Longer Updating Sqlite Schema

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, schema

I am using core data for my app and I never had any problems adding or removing columns until recently.  But now even if I make changes to my xcdatamodel and generate new and updated entity h/m files, sqlite doesn't seem to be picking up the changes.   I actually went over to the documents folder and inspected the create statement for the relevant tables in sqlite3 and I was able to confirm that the columns I added were missing.

I removed and redeployed the app several times to no avail.  Is it possible to do something to the app to make it disregard any schema changes being made through xcdatamodel?  I guess another thing I should mention is I recently started putting my entire projects folder in CVS so I wonder if something got messed up in the checkin and check out process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry.  I feel like an idiot.  A combination of "Reset Content and Settings" on the Simulator and a "Clean All Targets" in xcode seems to have fixed it.